# NetBeans and Android image

Tags: android, resources, netbeans-6.9

New to Android development and have decided to use NetBeans 6.9.1 as my IDE.  So far the process has been somewhat painful, but I'm getting things rolling.  However, I am creating an ImageView subclass for my first custom View and I can't figure out how to add my Box.png file to the project.  Drag and Drop doesn't work, there are no right-click options to add a file to the Resources folder, no dropdown menus to add images, no way to add the image to a package.  Could use some insight, thanks!

Comment: Any reason for not using eclipse? It's extremely painless to setup. Sorry for not being more constructive. :)

Comment: I agree, if you need to ask questions like this, you should probably use eclipse =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to the project folder and copy the images you want into the `res/drawable` folder. The IDE helps you a lot with code completion, error checking, etc... but that simple task can be done by hand.

Then, you can reference your resources by using something like: `R.drawable.image` Notice that I'm not using the image extension. If you wonder what `R` is, let me give you a brief explanation:

Each resource that is saved in the resources directory is referenced in the `R` class. That's a file that is autogenerated by Android and it's used to reference those resources from your code. In this case, it will be in `R.drawable.*` since it's a drawable resource. There are other kind of resources, like layouts: `R.layout.something` or strings `R.string.whatever`. That's essential for the android development, so you better read some tutorials (or buy books) in order for you to get started.

So, in your case will be something like `setImageDrawable(R.layout.wood);` However, I highly recommend to read first a couple of tutorials. Google about it, you will find tons of them.

Comment: Oh, yeah, 'cause that's *real* intuitive.  Ahem.  Sorry.  Alright, so now that I have moved the image, how can I call `this.setImageDrawable(...);` with the correct content?  Something like: `this.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable("wood.png"));` ?